# Testing for convergence of this function

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, indefinite-integrals

For the integral

$$\int_2^\infty \dfrac{x+1}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}dx .$$

Can I know if it's convergent or not?  If it does can I know how to evaluate it?

I tried to use $u$ substitution but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you mean $\int_2^{+\infty} \frac{x+1}{x-1} (x^2+x+1) dx$? This one divereges...

Comment: Seeing that the integral exists is easy as the integrand is roughly $\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: Yes, it's convergent because it is continuous around $2$ and when $x\to +\infty$, it is $\sim \cfrac{1}{x^2}$ which is integrable.

Comment: Danny's correct, srry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Apply partial fractions.

$$\frac{x+1}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}=\frac A{x-1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+x+1}$$

$$x+1=(A+B)x^2+(A-B+C)x+(A-C)$$

$$\therefore A=\frac23,B=-\frac23,C=-\frac13$$

Now we know that: $$\int \frac{x+1}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}dx=\frac23\int\frac1{x-1}dx-\frac13\int\frac{2x-1}{x^2+x+1}dx\\ =\frac23\ln|x-1|-\frac13\ln(x^2+x+1)=\frac13\ln\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2+x+1}$$

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\int^\infty_2\frac{x+1}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}dx&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int^n_2\frac{x+1}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}dx \\ \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac13\ln\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2+n+1}-\frac13\ln\frac17\right)\\ \\
&=-\frac13\ln\frac17\\ \\
&=\boxed{\dfrac13\ln7}
\end{align*}

Comment: This means it converges to $0$ right?

Comment: The limit approaches $0$, not the integral though ... according to my calculations

Comment: Ty, this what i got from my ti89!

Answer (score 2):

To see the convergence, just note that, the integrand behaves as

$$ \dfrac{x+1}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)} \sim_{\infty} \frac{x}{x^3}=\frac{1}{x^2}. $$

Answer (score 2):

According to [The Limit Comparison Test](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/limit_comparison.html) we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{\mathbf{2}}f(x)=1<\infty$$ so the improper integral converges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$0<\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{x+1}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}dx<\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{x+1}{(x-1)(x^2-1)}dx=\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}dx=1$$